Encode Struct to map[string]any with mapstructure.DecodeHookFunc
How can I encode struct with github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure, like:
type Struct struct {
    CreateDate *timestamppb.Timestamp `mapstructure:"create_date"`
}


to:
map[string]any{
    "create_date": "2024-01-01 12:00:00",
}

I'm trying something like
func TimestamppbToDatetimeHookFunc() mapstructure.DecodeHookFunc {
    return func(f reflect.Type, t reflect.Type, data any) (any, error) {
        if f != reflect.TypeOf(&timestamppb.Timestamp{}) {
            return data, nil
        }

        return data.(*timestamppb.Timestamp).AsTime().Format(time.DateTime), nil
    }
}

And
m := &Struct{CreateDate: timestamppb.Now()}

data := make(map[string]any)

d, err := mapstructure.NewDecoder(&mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
    Result:     &data,
    DecodeHook: TimestamppbToDatetimeHookFunc(),
})


if err := d.Decode(m); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

But d.Decode return error 'create_date' expected a map, got 'string'.
Maybe I can override output expected type with DecodeHookFuncValue (func(from reflect.Value, to reflect.Value) (interface{}, error)) with reflect, but how?

Same issue

The DecodeHook is applied to the whole input, not only the CreateDate field, therefore f type is Struct, not a timestamp. This should work:
func TimestamppbToDatetimeHookFunc() mapstructure.DecodeHookFunc {
    return func(f reflect.Type, t reflect.Type, data any) (any, error) {
        if f == reflect.TypeOf(&Struct{}) {
            v := data.(*Struct)

            return map[string]interface{}{
                "created_date": v.CreateDate.AsTime().Format(time.DateTime),
            }, nil
        }

        return data, nil
    }
}


I feel that go-viper/mapstructure does not take this issue very seriously, and many of the issues raised are ignored. I choose to use my own (for reference only):
package mapstruct

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func defaultDecoderConfig(config ...*DecoderConfig) *DecoderConfig {
    cfg := append(config, &DecoderConfig{})[0]
    if cfg.TagName == "" {
        cfg.TagName = "json"
    }
    return cfg
}

type DecoderConfig struct {
    DecodeHook func(reflect.Type, any) (any, error)
    TagName    string
}

func Decode(obj any, config ...*DecoderConfig) (map[string]any, error) {
    cfg := defaultDecoderConfig(config...)
    result := make(map[string]any)

    sv := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
    if sv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        sv = sv.Elem() // 解引用指针
    }

    if sv.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("expected a struct but got %s", sv.Kind())
    }

    for i, st := 0, sv.Type(); i < sv.NumField(); i++ {
        key := st.Field(i).Tag.Get(cfg.TagName)
        if key == "" || key == "-" {
            continue
        }

        fv := sv.Field(i) // 获得字段的值
        if hook := cfg.DecodeHook; hook != nil {
            value, err := hook(fv.Type(), fv.Interface())
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            result[key] = value
            continue
        }

        switch fv.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct: // 递归处理嵌套结构体
            m, err := Decode(fv.Interface())
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            result[key] = m
        default:
            result[key] = fv.Interface()
        }
    }

    return result, nil
}

This implementation can convert struct to map as follows:
type Person struct {
    Time time.Time `json:"time"`
    Name string    `json:"name"`
}

input := Person{time.Now(), "testName"}

m, err := mapstruct.Decode(input, &mapstruct.DecoderConfig{
    DecodeHook: func(t reflect.Type, a any) (v any, err error) {
        if t == reflect.TypeOf(time.Time{}) {
            value, _ := a.(time.Time)
            return value.Format(time.DateTime), nil
        }
        return a, nil
    },
})

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", m)
// input => {"name":"testName", "time":"2024-11-22 12:35:55"}


该包存放在 https://github.com/baagod/goconv 仓库中。
